# How to log in as "postgres" user with PostgreSQL 8.4.7 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL on my windows 7 desktop.

Usually PostgreSQL will create new account on my desktop, but when i want to switch user, there's no user named `postgres`. Then I checked the user folder in directory "C" and there's already a folder user named `postgres`.

But why can't I log in into my desktop using `postgres` account?

Comment: Why install (the three year old) 8.4 if the current version is 9.2?

Comment: ... and in particular, why 8.4.7 when the latest patch release of the fully-compatible 8.4 series is 8.4.14? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/index.html . BTW, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow; suggest moving to superuser.com .

Comment: Also, *why* do you need to log in as `postgres`? What are you trying to achieve by that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `postgres` account is a service account. It doesn't have the login right, and cannot be logged into. You can use `runas.exe` to run commands as the PostgreSQL user account, or shift-right-click on a program and use "Run as...".

In PostgreSQL 9.2 and above the installer puts PostgreSQL in the `NETWORKSERVICE` by default, so no `postgres` user account needs to be created.

In general, there is *no need* to run programs as the `postgres` user on Windows. Just specify the user to connect to the PostgreSQL server as, eg:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost dbname
```

Comment: thx mr.ranger ...
I need the shift-right-click action to run my psql prompt with postgres acount...

Comment: @user1511798 On Windows there isn't much point running `psql` as a different *windows* user; just connect to a different PostgreSQL account by specifying the user to connect as on the command line, GUI, or in `psql`'s interactive login prompt. See update.